# Release and quit Outlook object usng vb.net without closing outlook application

Tags: vb.net

i am using outlook 2010 and visual studio 2010

i've tried this code and it works fine:

```
    Dim objOLApp As Outlook.Application

    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Dim objExplorer As Outlook.Explorer

    Dim objSubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Dim objCalenderItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem

    Dim objOutlookFolders As Outlook.Folders

    Dim intFolderCtr As Integer

    Dim intSubFolderCtr As Integer

    Dim intAppointmentCtr As Integer

    ' >> Initialize The Base Objects

    objOLApp = New Outlook.Application

    objOutlookFolders = objOLApp.Session.Folders

    ' >> Loop Through The PST Files Added n Outlook

    For intFolderCtr = 1 To objOutlookFolders.Count


        objFolder = objOutlookFolders.Item(intFolderCtr)

        objExplorer = objFolder.GetExplorer()

        ' >> Loop Through The Folders In The PST File

        For intSubFolderCtr = 1 To objExplorer.CurrentFolder.Folders.Count


            objSubFolder = objExplorer.CurrentFolder.Folders.Item(intSubFolderCtr)

            ' >> Check if Folder Contains Appointment Items

            If objSubFolder.DefaultItemType = Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem Then


                ' >> Loop Through Appointment Items

                For intAppointmentCtr = 1 To objSubFolder.Items.Count


                    ' >> Get Teh Calender Item From The Calender Folder

                    objCalenderItem = objSubFolder.Items.Item(intAppointmentCtr)

                    ' >> Process Appointment Item Accordingly

                    If objCalenderItem.Start.ToShortDateString = Today.Date.ToShortDateString Then
                        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(1)
                        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Cells("col_seq").Value = DataGridView1.Rows.Count
                        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Cells("col_subject").Value = objCalenderItem.Subject
                        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Cells("col_date").Value = objCalenderItem.Start.ToShortDateString
                        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Cells("col_time").Value = objCalenderItem.Start.ToShortTimeString
                    End If


                Next

            End If

        Next

    Next

    ' >> Close Application

    Call objOLApp.Quit()

    ' >> Release COM Object

    Call System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objOLApp)

    objOLApp = Nothing
```

if the outlook is already opened, it will be terminated and closed and this is my problem i need to remove and release all the object and extra processes created without closing my outlook

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line of code:

```
Call objOLApp.Quit()
```

Set it `=Nothing` but don't quit the app... It stays open, you just aren't attached to it in the program.

Comment: i did that but when i check the process of the windows the OUTLOOK.EXE still running even after closing the programme

Comment: ... Isn't that what you said you wanted?? To leave outlook running?

Answer (score 0):

```
    objDoc.Close()
    objDoc.Application.Quit()
    objDoc.Application.DDETerminateAll()
    GC.Collect()
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(objDoc)<-- interop only


   try these something should work i have a similar problem  and good luck
```